# how do i keep changes to an icon after closing the page using localstorage

Tags: javascript

Its a "toDo" list. That function changes the icon to "complete". I wanna know how i can save this modification when i refresh or close the webpage.

I already have a function to save the tasks created, and i tried to call this function inside the function who changes the icon. Doesn't work.

I tried to save the changes "hidden". Doesn't work either.

```js
function completeTask(event) {

    const todoIcon = event.target;
    todoIcon.classList.add("hidden");

    const text = todoIcon.parentNode.childNodes[2];
    text.classList.add("risked");

    const taskToCompleteId = todoIcon.parentNode.parentNode.id
    const taskToComplete = document.getElementById(taskToCompleteId);

    taskToComplete.classList.add("done");
    taskToComplete.classList.remove("todo");

    const doneIcon = todoIcon.parentNode.childNodes[1];
    doneIcon.classList.remove("hidden");

    taskData.find((item) => {
        if (item.id === taskToCompleteId) {
            item.toDo = false;
        }
    })
    counter();
}
```

Comment: what does this function does? `counter();`

Comment: What do you not understand about the localstorage logic? It's key/value storage. Have you read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "doesn't work"

Have you seen the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) documentation?

For example:

`localStorage.setItem("status", "finished")`

```
localStorage.getItem("status")
> expected output: finished
```

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to use it in this case. I know "localstorage" saves strings, objects, etc. But, how can I save an icon's behavior? The code below I used to save the tasks in an array, but when I mark the finished icon and refresh the page, it returns without the markup.

localStorage.setItem("savedTask", JSON.stringify(taskData))

"taskData" is the array that holds the tasks.

Comment: You aren't being very clear. Are you trying to retrieve the data? Once you retrieve the data you can implement logic to add the formatting from your saved data?